# Creating new column using keywords

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to create a new column with values that correspond with keywords in an existing column in mysql.

I'm trying to determine if a practice is private or public based on keywords in their establishment's name.

In plain english what i'm trying to get is a new column called Practice and insert value private if keywords are specialist, gleneagles.

Would appreciate any help on this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to add a column to an existing table and then set that column's value (for each row) based on another column's value in that same row?

First, to create the column named `Practice` you can use MySQL's [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) command:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD Practice VARCHAR(20);
```

I'm not sure what type you are aiming for here, so I'm just going with `VARCHAR(20)`; you may also benefit from an `enum` based on the values you're using (or even a foreign-key to a lookup table).

After you've created your column, you can set its value:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Practice = CASE
    WHEN SomeColumn = 'specialist' THEN
        'private'
    WHEN SomeColumn = 'gleneagles' THEN
        'private'
    ELSE
        'public'
END
```

If you don't want records that don't match to be set, simply drop the `ELSE 'public'` and they'll be defaulted to `null`.

**UPDATE** (to select with wildcards)

If you need to update rows with the related data being contained within larger text and you need wildcards, you can use MySQL's `LIKE` operator:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Practice = CASE
    WHEN SomeColumn LIKE '%specialist%' THEN
        'private'
    WHEN SomeColumn LIKE '%gleneagles%' THEN
        'private'
    ELSE
        'public'
END
```

Alternatively, if you're only going to update to a single-value based on text containing multiple values, you can use a Regular Expression (via `REXEXP`) instead:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET Practice = CASE
    WHEN SomeColumn REGEXP 'specialist|gleneagles' THEN
        'private'
    ELSE
        'public'
END
```

Comment: hi thanks for that, i'm using the command line you gave me but its still coming back with 0 rows affected. the keywords are part of larger phrases, for example gleneagles is part of gleneagles hospital. so i've incorporated the use of the %wildcard but nothing is turning up still. any way around this?

Comment: @user3377434 I've updated the answer to include wildcard-based updates =]

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about denormalization, which means storing *derived* data. My initial reaction would be to not add another column, unless there were significant performance problems, instead I would create a view that gas the calculated value.

However, if you need the column, I would create a boolean column:

```
alter table mytable 
add is_private boolean;
```

Then populate it like this:

```
update mytable 
set is_private = (name like '%specialist%' or 
                  name like '%gleneagles%')
```